# Exclude argument null checks from dupFinder

Tags: duplicates, resharper, code-analysis, code-duplication, dupfinder

I'm using [dupFinder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/dupFinder.html) from the ReSharper Command Line Tools to analyze my code for duplicates.

If `null`-arguments are passed to public methods I'm respectively throwing an `ArgumentNullException`:

```
public void Foo(MyClass myClass, MyOtherClass myOtherClass)
{
    if (myClass == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myClass));
    if (myOtherClass == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myOtherClass));

    Console.WriteLine("Foo");
}

public void Bar(MyClass myClass, MyOtherClass myOtherClass)
{
    if (myClass == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myClass));
    if (myOtherClass == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myOtherClass));

    var whatEver = 23 + 42;
    Console.WriteLine("Bar is " + whatEver);
}
```

Unfortunately, dupFinder recognizes the lines with the null-checks as duplicates...
A way to get around this is to wrap these checks in regions...

```
#region ExcludeFromDupFinder
if (myClass == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myClass));
if (myOtherClass == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myOtherClass));
#endregion
```

...and execute dupFinder with the `--exclude-code-regions-option`:

```
dupfinder.exe c:\MyProjects\MySolution.sln /exclude-code-regions="ExcludeFromDupFinder"
```

But well... I'm not very pleased to have those unnecessary regions in the code as they're just adding noise and serve no real purpose apart from calming down dupFinder...

Although I don't think there's another way to solve this problem, I'm still asking: **Is there another (a *nicer*) way to exclude these null-checks from the analysis?**

I'm aware of the other dupFinder options like `--exclude-by-comment` or `--discard-fields`, but these are obviously having other purposes. An option like `--discard-null-checks` or `--discard-lines-by-pattern="someRegex"` would be nice.